# Highlight text in SharePoint document preview

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, office-interop

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218899/find-multiple-string-highlight-those-string-in-a-ms-word-document) shows a programmatic way for highlighting text in a word document. I am looking to do the same thing but for a document opened inside Sharepoint 2010.

[From this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/change-how-to-open-a-document-in-a-library-with-one-click-HA101729873.aspx) I understand that a document can be opened inside sharepoint itself [using the office webapp](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/02/01/embedding-a-powerpoint-deck-on-sharepoint-2010.aspx) (a bit of a hack in 2010, [better in 2013](http://blog.creative-sharepoint.com/2013/06/embedding-a-powerpoint-presentation-into-a-sharepoint-2013-page/)) or in the local user instance of word/excel/...

I would need programmatic, read-only control over that preview. Mainly to highlight particular text fragments. I would think it should be possible to do this for the webapp instance but not for the locally started instance. Though I have't found any example code or pointers how to approach this. Commercial solutions are not an option.

Edit:

- [Related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23995/embedding-office-files-into-sharepoint-pages)
- There [seems to be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms582023.aspx) some kind of an api
  for the Excel web app but [not](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/webapps-word/is-there-a-word-web-app-api-available/ab9b98c9-3d14-49e1-98a1-fe7a0f202932?msgId=f071cee1-a415-4ce2-8992-41f0b1812217) [for](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/52852/186727.aspx#186727) [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058488/public-api-to-manage-documents-in-office-web-apps)

Comment: with no reaction, have put in a vote to have the question migrated to the sharepoint site, maybe that is a better place for this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is not possible, but happy to be proven wrong. The only solution I see is to do the highlighting on the server side up front (e.g., using com or openxml libs) in a separate copy of the document or on the fly (e.g., [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239208/view-docx-documents-in-webbrowser-control)). Then serve the processed document to the client.