# display docx file into a winform in c#

Tags: winforms, file, docx

I'm trying to make my program have the ability to display a Microsoft Word file on a form but not having any luck in doing so. I want to be able to open the file and display it on the form as a Read-Only. So basically just display it's contents. Various users on the web have recommended displaying files in the WebBrowser control (under toolbox). I have tried this but failed to get it working. My end goal is to be able to annotate on top of the web browser (or something of similar manner) and subsequently save the annotations along with the opened file.

I'm not that experienced in the C# language too so any help on how to achieve my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening Word (.docx) files on a Windows Form C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521086/opening-word-docx-files-on-a-windows-form-c-sharp)

Comment: @GuidoG, A duplicate in the purest sense.   An exact copy!